# Using the adjective "early" or the adverb "earlier"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am going to say I am usually **in time** at my meetings. I wonder which choice is the more idiomatic one in English to be used within the construction below:

> - Habitually, I usually arrive at my meetings five minutes.........

a. early 
b. earlier

**Added:** Long time ago, I asked a [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109220/early-vs-earlier), which contained a comparison between a current time and sometime earlier to that. Here, I think the there is not such a comparison involved. However, that is what I think. Others are free to dispute it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Early vs Earlier](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109220/early-vs-earlier)

Comment: (b) would only make sense if you had arrived later than usual today. It would imply 'earlier than this' or 'earlier than I did today'. (By the way, you don't need both _habitually_ and _usually_ in the same sentence.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use **early** as a native speaker but both are acceptable, if you use *earlier*, I recommend you change your sentence to:

> Habitually, I usually arrive at my meetings five minutes **earlier than scheduled**